# Checking visibility with jQuery (debug)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I followed a few posts to be able to check the visibility of a div :

**HTML :**

```
<div class="language" onclick="Show_Div()">
  <div class="menu-langues">
    //my code here
  </div>
</div>
```

**Script :**

```
function Show_Div() {
$Div_id = "menu-langues";
    if ( $(Div_id).is(':hidden')) {
        ($Div_id).show();
    }
    else {
        ($Div_id).hide();
    }
}
```

**Console :**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Div_id is not defined
```

I can't see what i did wrong, can someone help me with this?

Thank's ! :)

Comment: `Div_id ` is different than `$Div_id `. Anyway what you want is just `$('.menu-langues').toggle()`

Comment: Use var Div_id = "menu-langues" instead of $Div_id = "menu-langues";

Comment: And just as a side note, calling a method `Show_Div()` which can result in doing exactly the opposite (hiding div) looks incredibely unrelevant imho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't mix inline event handlers like onclick with jQuery. jQuery handlers will do a better job and have extra features. And, as `@Rory McCrossan` said, just use `toggle`.

Code:

```
$('.language').click(function(){
    // Show if hidden and hide if visible
    $('.menu-langues').toggle();
});
```

Html (no inline handler):

```
<div class="language">
  <div class="menu-langues">
    //my code here
  </div>
</div>
```

If you had multiples of the same button on the page, you can target the selection using a scoped selector (second parameter defines the scope):

```
$('.language').click(function(){
    // Show if hidden and hide if visible
    $('.menu-langues', this).toggle();
});
```

Comment: I used this code because it's clean and works well. Thank's a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

You've defined a variable, then used a different one in your code in the if-statement.

```
if ( $(Div_id).is(':hidden')) {
```

should be

```
if ( $($Div_id).is(':hidden')) {
```

That should solve the error. However, to get working code I'd recommend writing like this:

```
function Show_Div() {
    $Div_id = $(".menu-langues");
    if ( $Div_id.is(':hidden')) {
        $Div_id.show();
    }
    else {
        $Div_id.hide();
    }
}
```

This way you're turning the variable `$Div_id` into a jQuery object, on which you can execute functions. By saving it in the variable, the code doesn't have to look for the element over and over again.

Comment: Still it is missing dot for class selector

Comment: It's missing a lot of things :-) I answered too quickly. I adjusted my answer. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: i've tried your code, and now the console displays `Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function`

Comment: That probably means that you didn't include jQuery (in the right place). I'm afraid I can't help you with that with the amount of code you've supplied.

Answer (score 1):

Some errors: menu-langues is a class not an ID, so, you can reference this with jQuery as: `$('.menu-langues')`
If you need reference to an ID, use jQuery:  `$('#menu-langues')`

So, use '`.`' to reference a class and '`#`' to reference an ID.

You used `$Div_id = "menu-langues";` ...and I changed it to: `Div_id = "menu-langues";`

And too you write `$(Div_id).show();` and I fixed to: `$(Div_id).show();`

The snipped code fixed and working:

```js
function Show_Div() {
var Div_id = ".menu-langues"; // is a class, not ID
    if ( $(Div_id).is(':hidden')) {
        $(Div_id).show();
    }
    else {
        $(Div_id).hide();
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="language" onclick="Show_Div()">
  <div class="menu-langues">
    test of visibility
  </div>
</div>
<button onClick="javascript:Show_Div();">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable name is `$Div_id` not `Div_id`. Also you are trying to select with class name so you would need to prepend a `.` to your selector.

Your code should look like:

```
function Show_Div() {
    $Div_id = ".menu-langues";
    if ( $($Div_id).is(':hidden')) {
        $($Div_id).show();
    }
    else {
        $($Div_id).hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: `($Div_id).show();` is invalid jQuery...You asleep today? :)

Comment: I wasn't trying to improve the logic, rather just answering the question asked.

Comment: @elem4th: Questions often have multiple problems (like this one). You need to fix them all, else your own answer will need fixing :)

Comment: @elem4th you're missing the `$` prefixes on the jQuery objects, ie. `$($Div_id)`. If you want to fix the logic, just use `$('.menu-languages').toggle()` and be done with it

Comment: Oh yes.. I didn't notice that line. Thanks. Updated.

Answer (score -1):

The code should be more like:

```
function Show_Div() {
    var $Div_id = "menu-langues";
    if ( $($Div_id).is(':hidden')) {
        $($Div_id).show();
    } else {
        $($Div_id).hide();
    }
}
```

It's also worth mentioning that the convention for JavaScript variable names and function names is camelCase.